# Checking aria with Jest/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to check if `aria-expanded` changes after a button click. This is my component

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { ArrowTemplate } from './ArrowTemplate';
import { colors } from '../../utils/css';
import { Text } from '../Text';

const Accordion = ({
  rtl, content, color, title, className,
}) => {
  const element = useRef(null);
  const [isAccordionExpanded, setIsAccordionExpanded] = useState(false);
  const toggleAccordion = () => {
    setIsAccordionExpanded(!isAccordionExpanded);
  };
  const height = element.current ? element.current.scrollHeight : '0';
  return (
    <div className={`accordion-section ${className}`}>
      <button className={'accordion-btn'} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
        <p className={'accordion-title'}>
          <Text isRtl={rtl}>{title}</Text>
        </p>
        <ArrowTemplate
          direction={isAccordionExpanded ? 'up' : 'down'}
          onClick={toggleAccordion}
          rtl={rtl}
          color={color}
        />
      </button>
      <AccordionContent
        className={'accordion-content'}
        height={height}
        isAccordionExpanded={isAccordionExpanded}
        ref={element}
        aria-expanded={isAccordionExpanded}
      >
        <div className={'accordion-text'}>
          <Text isRtl={rtl}>{content}</Text>
        </div>
      </AccordionContent>
    </div>
  );
};

export const StyledAccordion = styled(Accordion)`
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    text-align: ${({ rtl }) => (rtl ? 'right' : 'left')};        
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
      .accordion-btn {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: ${colors.LG_GREY_4};
        color: ${colors.LG_GREY_5};
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 40px 18px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        :hover,
        :focus,
        :active {
          background-color: ${colors.LG_GREY_6};
        }
        .accordion-title {
          ${({ rtl }) => (rtl ? 'right: 50px;' : 'left: 50px;')};
          position: absolute;
          font-weight: 600;
          font-size: 14px;
        }
      }
  `;

export const AccordionContent = styled.div`
        max-height: ${({ isAccordionExpanded, height }) => (isAccordionExpanded ? height : '0')}px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: ${colors.LG_GREY_7};
        transition: max-height 0.7s;
        .accordion-text {
          font-weight: 400;
          font-size: 14px;
          padding: 18px;
        }
  `;
```

Here are my tests

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { StyledAccordion, AccordionContent } from '../Accordion';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('<StyledAccordion/>',
  () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(<StyledAccordion/>);
    });
    it('should match the snapshot', () => {
      expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
    it('should originally have aria-expanded set to false', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(AccordionContent).props()['aria-expanded']).toBe(false);
    });
    it('should set aria-expanded to true onClick', () => {
      wrapper.find('.accordion-btn').simulate('click');
      expect(wrapper.find(AccordionContent).props()['aria-expanded']).toBe(true);
    });
  });
```

And here's what I'm getting in the console

```
 FAIL  src/components/Accordion/test/Accordion.test.js (21.497s)
  ● <StyledAccordion/> › should originally have aria-expanded set to false

    Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

      16 |     });
      17 |     it('should originally have aria-expanded set to false', () => {
    > 18 |       expect(wrapper.find(AccordionContent).props()['aria-expanded']).toBe(false);
         |                                             ^
      19 |     });
      20 |     it('should set aria-expanded to true onClick', () => {
      21 |       wrapper.find('.accordion-btn').simulate('click');

      at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1636:13)
      at ShallowWrapper.single [as props] (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1160:17)
      at Object.props (src/components/Accordion/test/Accordion.test.js:18:45)

  ● <StyledAccordion/> › should set aria-expanded to true onClick

    Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

      19 |     });
      20 |     it('should set aria-expanded to true onClick', () => {
    > 21 |       wrapper.find('.accordion-btn').simulate('click');
         |                                      ^
      22 |       expect(wrapper.find(AccordionContent).props()['aria-expanded']).toBe(true);
      23 |     });
      24 |   });

      at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1636:13)
      at ShallowWrapper.single [as simulate] (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:1118:17)
      at Object.simulate (src/components/Accordion/test/Accordion.test.js:21:38)
```

How can I test attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking attribute by verifying props is fine. Simulating click is fine.
The only cause test fails is how `shallow()` works under the hood.

You may figure out that by yourselves by checking what `wrapper.debug()` returns(say by adding `console.log(wrapper.debug())`)

You will see something like `<StyledComponentConsumer><Component ...></StyledComponentConsumer>`. So the reason is `shallow()` does not render nested component. Say, if there were no `styled-components` and you tried to `shallow(<Accordion />).find('span')`(assuming that `<Text>` should be rendered as `<span>`) you will never find that as well.

**First solution** may be using `mount()` instead of `shallow()`(you should not even need to change test). But I would like to go different way(just an opinion though: https://hackernoon.com/why-i-always-use-shallow-rendering-a3a50da60942)

Read more about `shallow vs mount` difference at https://medium.com/@Yohanna/difference-between-enzymes-rendering-methods-f82108f49084

**Another approach** is to use [`.dive()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) like

```
wrapper.dive().find(...)
```

or even at initialization time:

```
const wrapper = shallow(...).dive();
```

**And finally** you may just export two versions: base one(and write tests against that) and wrapped into `styled-components` theming. Needs slightly more changes in code. And dislike approaches above tests will not require updates each time you add more HOC wrappers(say wrapping component into `styled-components`, then connect to `redux` and finally adding `withRouter` - tests will still work the same this way). But from the other side this approach does not test your component as it's actually integrated so I'm not really sure if this approach is better.